# Is the FPCA just a PCA on coefficients?

Tags: python, pca, functional-data-analysis

Is functional principal-components analysis (FPCA) on basis representations just a PCA on the component coefficients? The following seems to indicate that yes, it is:

```
import numpy as np
import skfda as fda
from skfda.preprocessing.dim_reduction import FPCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# get Canadian weather data
weather = fda.datasets.fetch_weather()
weather_data_grid = fda.FDataGrid(data_matrix = weather.data.data_matrix[:, :, 0],
                                  grid_points = weather.data.grid_points,
                                  domain_range = weather.data.domain_range)
# do an FPCA
weather_basis = fda.representation.basis.FourierBasis(domain_range = (0.0, 365.0),
                                                      n_basis = 25, period = 365)
weather_data_basis = weather_data_grid.to_basis(weather_basis)
weather_fpca = FPCA(n_components = 25)
weather_fpca.fit(weather_data_basis)
# do a regular PCA on the coefficients of the basis functions
pca = PCA(n_components = 25)
pca.fit(weather_data_basis.coefficients)
# compare results
np.allclose(weather_fpca.explained_variance_ratio_, pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
# --> True
np.allclose(weather_fpca.components_.coefficients, pca.components_)
# --> True
```

If so, then the basis representation FPCA can be summarized by the following simple procedure:

- compute coefficients of the data by projecting on a basis
- perform a regular PCA on these coefficients

Is that all there is to it, or am I missing something?

Thank you!